# Как собрать Chromium?

Tags: компиляция, chromium

Итак, хочу свой браузер по типу Браузер ВасиПупкина. Все везде пишут: «бери код Chromium, меняй под себя и получи себе браузер». Но знаний у меня 0. Скачал я эти исходники и сижу не знаю, что собирать, как собирать, где собирать. Нашёл тут [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14195/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80?rq=1):

> 1. Скачать Chromium
> 2. Сменить `title` на `"%username%'s браузер` по аналогии с Я.Браузер и Mail-браузером
> 3. Внедрить в него malware, spyware и rootkit (опционально)
> 4. PROFIT!!!

Но опять же, во-первых я не хочу внедрять malware, а во-вторых где этот `title` менять? Кстати официальную документацию я не понял, хоть английский я знаю неплохо.

Comment: Хромиум на i7 из исходников собирается примерно 4 часа =)

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

Comment: вот поисковик по исходникам https://cs.chromium.org/

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я думаю, вашу ссылку на инструкцию по сборке можно считать ответом :)

Comment: Кстати, не знаю, можно ли считать дубликатом, [но](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14195/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80?rq=1)…

Comment: можно пойти по более простому пути, взять Qt и WebView, его собрать в разы проще

Comment: @StrangerintheQ прав. Вот вам простая инструкция: 1) Скачиваете и устанавливаете Qt Creator; 2) После запуска в окне Welcome выбираете Examples; 3) В списке примеров как раз есть пример простого браузера — открываете пример; 4) Нажимаете кнопку «Собрать»; 5) PROFIT.